# Non Blocking Retry Support for KafkaStreams

Tags: spring-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there support for non blocking retry functionality for KafkaStreams in Spring Kafka? I see details mentioned in [this link](https://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/retrytopic/retry-topic-combine-blocking.html) related to setting it up for Kafka Listener.

In case non blocking retry works with Kafka Stream, kindly guide with documentation or example.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the use case for a non-blocking retry feature in Kafka Streams? Maybe create an issue/discussion on GH and let us know?

Comment: Basically we want to create a Kafka Stream which consumes data from a particular topic, do some processing and on success it produces data to sink topic. However, if there is any sort of failure in processing it pushes to retry topic and it should follow retry related pattern defined here (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/retrytopic.html#:~:text=Achieving%20non%2Dblocking%20retry%20%2F%20dlt,class%20to%20simplify%20that%20bootstrapping). This pattern is supported with spring related configuration changes in normal Kafka Consumers but don’t see its reference for Kafka Streams.